# GridView Search with textbox string

Tags: vb.net, gridview

I have a DataGrid that is populated with (not from a datasource) and I am trying to search the grid based on the text entered into the textbox. When I click the button I get object reference error but I am not sure why. The idea is the search will find the word and then highlight the cells yellow.

```
Private Sub btnApply_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnApply.Click
        Dim temp As Integer = 0
        For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.RowCount - 1
            For j As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.ColumnCount - 1
                If DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value.ToString = txtGridSearch.Text Then --'Object reference not set to an instance of an object
                    temp = 1
                    DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(j).Style.BackColor = Color.Yellow
                End If
            Next
        Next
        If temp = 0 Then
            MsgBox("Item not found")
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: The title says `GridView`, the question says `DataGrid` and the code says `DataGridView`. Names are important. Those three are all different things. If you're using a `DataGridView` then say that. Don't be lazy with naming because it can lead to confusion and may wind up with you getting advice that isn't actually relevant to your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We know that `DataGridView1` is initialized when you have the error because you referred to `DataGridView1.RowCount` earlier successfully. `DataGridView1.Rows(i)` is likely valid too, because `i` is smaller than `RowCount`. `DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(j)` is likely valid too, because `j` is smaller than `ColumnCount`.

So either `DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value` or `txtGridSearch` is `Nothing`. Check for those cases:

```
If (DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value IsNot Nothing) AndAlso (txtGridSearch IsNot Nothing) AndAlso (DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value.ToString = txtGridSearch.Text) Then
```